# Scrapy: 'return' plain text to item (Field)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am scraping the fields from http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/psearch/QResult16.aspx?qref=15844. All fields are properly 'returned' on console, with usual HTML tags. I need to pipe these fields to a CSV file (CSVItemExporter). If I try to put the html response in a temp register and apply the converter operation in the second step when assigning to the item field, I get a separate set of error messages.

I tried solutions in BeautifulSoup get_text and html2text, as in [Is it possible that Scrapy to get plain text from raw html data directly instead of using xPath selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721782/is-it-possible-that-scrapy-to-get-plain-text-from-raw-html-data-directly-instead) and [How can I get all the plain text from a website with Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156780/how-can-i-get-all-the-plain-text-from-a-website-with-scrapy). The solutions therein 'print' well but fail to assign to the respective fields.

Any converter operation on the response function (converter(response +extract)) leads to errors such as "str object has no attribute 'get_text'" (html2text) or returns text with random \r\n items inserted (BeautifulSoup). 
I suspect this is because of hard CRs in the original text, which the original author may have put to keep stuff aligned. How do I get around this problem? Python 2.7 on Win 32.

Comment: Please post the specific fields html with which your getting errors.

Comment: @Vikas: here is the relevant log: DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/psearch/QResult16.aspx?qref=15944>

 {'q_date': [u'30.04.2015'],
  'q_house': u'LOK SABHA',
  'q_main': u'(a) whether a huge amount is outstanding from various State Electricity Boards and power companies against \r\nthe coal supplied to them by Coal India Ltd. and its subsidiary companies;\r\n\r\n',
  'q_ministry': [u'COAL'],
  'q_name': [u'Poddar Smt. Aparupa'],
  'q_no': [u'6107'],
  'q_subject': [u'OUTSTANDING DUES '],
  'q_type': [u'UNSTARRED ']} NOTE the \r\n in field q_main.

Comment: here is the log for another page: Scraped from <200 http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/psearch/QResult16.aspx?qref=15844>

 {'q_date': [u'08.05.2015'],
  'q_house': u'LOK SABHA',
  'q_main': u'(a) whether the Government has notified a compre-\r\nhensive regulatory framework for Television Rating\r\nAgency;',}  ends and here is the source html (text): (a) whether the Government has notified a compre-
hensive regulatory framework for Television Rating
Agency;
Confirms my doubts that there are hard carriage returns in the source text (badly formed html). How to handle this?

Comment: <kbd> (a) whether the Government has notified a compre-
hensive regulatory framework for Television Rating
Agency;</kbd>